# Vidyo.io Integration in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, video, notifications, vidyo

I'm new in IOS. I'm working on a Video Call project in swift. i'm using `vidyo.io` SDK for video Call and message chat. But I have some questions

1. If my app is in kill state or my phone is locked. how can I receive call Notification.
2. Some SDK's have VoIP support for Call notification in locked State. `vidyo.io` have support for VoIP? If yes how can I implement.
3. `vidyo.io` Documentation have some methods for use camera, microphone, Customize UI etc can we implement all these methods in swift?

if any one have good tutorials or helping materials please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a Vidyo.io sample app built with Swift here: https://github.com/Vidyo/customview-swift-ios

Vidyo.io is a CPaaS focused on video chat. You can use the service for voice only, but you probably have better options if that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Great Swift blogpost here: https://vidyo.io/blog/how-to/vidyo-io-using-swift-build-ios-video-chat-app/